# How to pass a javascript object using jquery to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below HTML file . I am trying to pass the item object to the javascript function : linkClickFunc so that i can process it further.

But i am unable to do it with the below syntax . Can someone please guide me as to what am i doing wrong .

```
    <div class="container">
  <h2>CodeConfig Keys</h2>
  <br>
  <div id="key-buttons">
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function linkClickFunc(item)
{
  console.log(item);
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    CodeConfigkeys = {"ENV": [{"NAME": "Subhayan", "Values": [{"AGE": 33, "SEX": "Male"}]}, {"NAME": "Mary", "Values": [{"AGE": 29, "SEX": "Female"}]}], "DB_PARAMS": [{"NAME": "SQL_CONNECTIONS_DB", "Values": "templates"}, {"NAME": "SQL_CONNECTIONS_COLLECTION", "Values": "dbtemplates"}]};
    var html_str = "";
    $.each( CodeConfigkeys, function( key, value ){
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"btn-group dropdown\">";
    html_str = html_str + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-primary-spacing\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" id=\"" + "CodeConfigMenus" + "\">" + key;
    html_str = html_str + "</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>";
    html_str = html_str + "<div class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
    value.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    console.log(item);
    console.log (typeof item);
    html_str = html_str + "<li><a onclick=\"linkClickFunc($(" + "'" + item + "'" + "));\">" + item["NAME"] + "</a></li>";
    });
    html_str = html_str + "</div></div>";
    });
    console.log(html_str);
    $("#key-buttons").html(html_str);

});
</script>
```

I have searched for possible solutions on the internet but could not hit upon the right one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store item in the `data()` on the element, then bind an unobtrusive event handler to it and read that data attribute back out.

Comment: I edited the question to give the source code. But i am not sure i followed your suggestion

Comment: If  `item` is an object, the HTML output would be `<a onclick="linkClickFunc([object Object])"></a>`. You need to add an event listener for the click event.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what the error is . Forgive my lack of knowledge in this subject but isn't the function an click event listener ?

Comment: I meant programmatically, i.e. `link.addEventListener('click', yourFunction)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your line

```
html_str = html_str + "<li><a onclick=\"linkClickFunc($(" + "'" + item + "'" + "));\">" + item["NAME"] + "</a></li>";
```

with

```
html_str = html_str + "<li><a onclick='linkClickFunc("+JSON.stringify(item)+")'>" + item["NAME"] + "</a></li>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Works perfectly.

Comment: That is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.stringify() to pass the object as a string. Of course you need to escape the double quote to be recognize as real double quotes. **JSON.stringify(item)**

```
html_str = html_str + "<li><a onclick=\"linkClickFunc($(" + "'" + JSON.stringify(item) + "'" + "));\">" + item["NAME"] + "</a></li>";
```

Then for the function, parse the JSON object back to string. **JSON.parse(item)**

```
function linkClickFunc(item)
{
  var obj = JSON.parse(item);
  console.log(item);
}
```

I have not tested the code but you should handle double quote for string conversion and parsing.